# Ler ponteiro de string em C

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, alocação

Esta é a pergunta:
4. Faça um programa que receba do usuário o tamanho de uma string e chame uma
função para alocar dinamicamente essa string. Em seguida, o usuário deverá informar
o conteúdo dessa string. O programa imprime a string sem suas vogais.
O codigo funciona normalmente quando a palavra não tem um espaço (' '), nao imprime as vogais, mas quando a palavra lida tem espaço, por exemplo: 'bom dia', imprime tudo nada a ver, símbolos, algm pode ajudar?
Codigo abaixo

```
char *ptr;
int i, x;
printf("Tamanho do vetor:\n");
scanf("%d", &x);
ptr = malloc(x * sizeof(char));
scanf("%s", ptr);
for (i=0; i<x; i++) {
if (*(ptr+i) != 'a' && *(ptr+i) != 'e' && *(ptr+i) != 'i' && *(ptr+i) != 'o' && *(ptr+i) != 'u') {
printf("%c", *(ptr+i));
}
}
```

Comment: Com o formato que você especificou no scanf ele encerrará a leitura ou quando chegar ao final da linha ou quando encontrar o primeiro branco. Como você não testa se chegou ao final da string você vai imprimir lixo de memória. No seu exemplo sua string conterá apenas "bom".

Comment: então como poderia fazer?

Answer (score 0):

a maneira mais indicada para trabalhar com string no c( palavras composta) seria usar o scanf(" %[^\n]s");. O [^\n] vai ler todo a sua string ate o \n, e o espaço que se da entre " e o % é uma maneira de limpar o buffer do teclado. Pode ser esse seu problema

Comment: obrigado, consegui arrumar